# Avoid adding a duplicate child in a node, using the Tree.hh library from Kasper Peeters

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to get a hold of the tree container library that is implemented here: http://tree.phi-sci.com/index.html . I have been looking for a tree container and the recommendation here seems to be this one or the graph library.

In this particular example, I'm trying to make a N-ary tree, and add some nodes to it. The problem is that I don't want to duplicate the items. So before adding something, I check if it exist first.

The intended tree should be this one:

```
A
---- A.1
B
---- B.1
---- B.2
C
---- C.1
D
---- D.1
---- D.2
E
---- E.1
---- E.2
```

The data arrives in an arbitrary order by pairs of strings. For example if I get "D","D.1", I need to create the node "D" if it doesn't exist, add the node "D.1" inside "D" if it doesn't exist, and I don't care whether A,B, or C exist previously or not.

This is my code so far

```
#include "tree.hh"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    //Init the database
    std::string zones[10] = {"A",
                             "A",
                             "B",
                             "C",
                             "B",
                             "D",
                             "D",
                             "E",
                             "E",
                             "E"};

    std::string subZones[10] = {"A.1",
                                "A.1",
                                "B.1",
                                "C.1",
                                "B.2",
                                "D.1",
                                "D.2",
                                "E.1",
                                "E.1",
                                "E.2"};

    //Prepare the strings for the categories
    std::string tempZone = "";
    std::string tempSubZone = "";

    //Prepare the tree
    tree<std::string> bodyTree;
    tree<std::string>::iterator zoneIt, subZoneIt, topIt;
    topIt = bodyTree.begin();

    //Loop the entire database
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

        //Grab the data
        tempZone = zones[i];
        tempSubZone = subZones[i];

        //Check if we have that zone already
        zoneIt=find(bodyTree.begin(), bodyTree.end(), tempZone);

        //If we don't have the zone, add it to the tree
        if(zoneIt==bodyTree.end()){

            bodyTree.insert(topIt, tempZone);

            std::cout << "Added new Zone: "<< tempZone << "\n";

        }

        //Now we have the zone for sure, we do the same with the subZone

        //Check if we have that subzone already
        subZoneIt=find(bodyTree.begin(zoneIt), bodyTree.end(zoneIt), tempSubZone);

        //If the subZone doesn't exist, add it to the zone
        if(subZoneIt==bodyTree.end(zoneIt)){

            bodyTree.insert(zoneIt, tempSubZone);

            std::cout << "Added new subZone "<< tempSubZone << " --> to --> " << tempZone << "\n";

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Added new Zone: A
Added new subZone A.1 --> to --> A
Added new subZone A.1 --> to --> A
Added new Zone: B
Added new subZone B.1 --> to --> B
Added new Zone: C
Added new subZone C.1 --> to --> C
Added new subZone B.2 --> to --> B
Added new Zone: D
Added new subZone D.1 --> to --> D
Added new subZone D.2 --> to --> D
Added new Zone: E
Added new subZone E.1 --> to --> E
Added new subZone E.1 --> to --> E
Added new subZone E.2 --> to --> E
```

So as you can see, the first level nodes are fine, and only added once. The second level nodes are added multiple times despise trying to find out if they previously exist in that particular node.

My guess is that the code that uses the iterator for the siblings is wrong, so it should be one of these two lines:

```
//Check if we have that subzone already
subZoneIt=find(bodyTree.begin(zoneIt), bodyTree.end(zoneIt), tempSubZone);

//If the subZone doesn't exist, add it to the zone
if(subZoneIt==bodyTree.end(zoneIt)){
```

I wonder if somebody can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. the first time you insert a zone `zoneIt` will be equal to `bodyTree.end()`. So you need to insert another call to `find(bodyTree.begin(), bodyTree.end(), tempZone);` to make it point to the newly inserted element.
2. `insert` adds the new element as a sibling of the current zone. But you want to use `append_child` instead to add it as a child of the current zone.

With [these](http://pastebin.com/KV640PhA) changes added to your code I get the following output:

```
Added new Zone: A
Added new subZone A.1 --> to --> A
Added new Zone: B
Added new subZone B.1 --> to --> B
Added new Zone: C
Added new subZone C.1 --> to --> C
Added new subZone B.2 --> to --> B
Added new Zone: D
Added new subZone D.1 --> to --> D
Added new subZone D.2 --> to --> D
Added new Zone: E
Added new subZone E.1 --> to --> E
Added new subZone E.2 --> to --> E
```